# Error 1054 Unknown Column while Inserting into Table in Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I'm getting a very frustrating error while attempting to insert a simple record into a table in AWS Aurora MySQL, using Workbench to connect. Even when using the scripting tool by right-clicking the table name and selecting "Send to SQL Editor-->Insert Statement" or by doing a select top 1000 rows and utilizing the grid function to enter, then "Apply" the new row, it does not work.

The error I continue to get is `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'NEW.USER_ID' in 'field list'`

there is very clearly a column called USER_ID on my table. Any ideas? I'm connected as the admin user. I've been able to execute create trigger and create view scripts on this database, but just not insert a row into this table.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a table named `NEW`.

Comment: `NEW.columnname` is used in trigger definitions to refer to the new value being assigned to a column. It shouldn't be used in other contexts.

Comment: You need to post the `INSERT` query if you want specific help

Comment: Turns out I had a trigger on here that had quotes around the NEW.columnname. Once I removed those quotes, it worked fine. Thanks for pointing out that it was a trigger issue, that led me to the solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment above, it turns out my issue was around the trigger syntax. I was using back-quotes around NEW.columnname, and when I removed those quotes it all worked fine.

Comment: If the column name needs to be quoted, the syntax would be ```NEW.`colname` ```